# Join multiindex pandas will single index to add missing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table which filters how many reports are created each month, and in most months there are some reports which aren't created - therefore they dont show in the pivot table. However I'm struggling to join the pivot table dataframe to a single index dataframe which contains all reports to show the blank ones.

```
current_month = pd.pivot_table(df1['Report Name'], columns='Status of Report', values='Status Count, dropna=False, fill_value=0)


pivot table example (sorry for formatting):  
Status of Report | Ignore Report | Good Report | Critical Report 
Report Name
UK               |       1       |      5      |       1
France           |       4       |      2      |       0
Germany          |       2       |      1      |       0
Italy            |       2       |      2      |       0
```

Now if there were no reports at all for say Belgium, how could i add a row which had all zeros? I've tried creating a report dataframe which lists all the countries then tried joining the pivot table to all_reports_df but i constantly get errors

```
all_reports = {'Report Name': ['UK', 'France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Belgium']}
all_reports_df = pd.Dataframe(all_reports)
all_reports_df.join(current_month, on='Report Name', how='left')
```

This join makes no change to all_reports_df. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0):

try via `reindex()`:

```
df=(df.set_index('Status of Report')
      .reindex(['UK', 'France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Belgium'])
      .reset_index()
      .fillna(df).fillna(0))
```

**OR**

If there is only 1 entry then you can try:

```
df.loc[len(df)]=['Belgium',0,0,0]
```

**OR**

via `merge()`:

```
all_reports = {'Status of Report': ['UK', 'France', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Belgium']}
all_reports_df = pd.DataFrame(all_reports)
df=all_reports_df.merge(df,how='left').fillna(df).fillna(0)
```